# How to delete a column in a content type?

Tags: column

How to delete a column in a content type? The columns are not clickable? And content types inheriting from based documents or items ct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have your solution. Open SharePoint Manager 2010. Expand the Site > Expand the Content Types > Click on the "Content Type" that giving you trouble. See the ReadOnly property to False.

I was able to set it true and false and got the behaviour you are having. Hope this helps.

So, ReadOnly for the content type (not the field level) level.

Comment: 100% on target. Thanks Bill. Yes, Readonly property was set to "True". I changed it to False and wala. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I know sealed or read only columns are not enabled for deletion. hmm. now how do you find a column is sealed or not. well, I use SP Manager 2010 to find out sealed columns. I think there is powershell to determine that as well.

But this may not be the case either. anyone else want to input their observations?

I doubt thats your case because all of your columns are non-clickable. hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the top level site settings? Unless you are in the site that the content type and/or column was created you will not be able to click on it. Also, you may not have permission to do so.

Once you are able to click on the column, click on it. There you will find a "delete" button.

This is how I understand it. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Check a workaround in my blog to enable the delete button using PowerShell
http://shareyourpoint.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/how-to-enable-delete-button-to-delete-sharepoint-2010-content-type-column/

Here is the PowerShell script to bring back the Content Type delete button:

```
$site = Get-SPSite-Identity “http://sharepointsite/sites/test“ 

$ctype =$site.RootWeb.Fields | ?{$_.InternalName -eq“InternalFieldName”}

$ctype.AllowDeletion=“true”

$ctype.Update()
```

Run the above script from the server and check that the content type button now appears.

Comment: I'd be great if you can detail the answer a bit instead of just linking to your blog. While it might answer the question, blog content comes and goes and your answer may no longer exist in the future.