# Inadvertently Created Content Type Column and now can't delete it

Tags: content-type, column, read-only, 2010

I created a column on my root site's content type and now cannot delete it.  It is somehow locked as "Read Only" and I have tried PowerShell and SharePoint Designer 2010 and every option I could find to no avail.  This is on our top level site and I am afraid this additional "Name" column could conflict with other fields and will cause problems down the road.  I cannot delete the whole content type because this is a live site with hundreds of lists associated with it.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated!

[image: badContentType]

Comment: Possibly related [http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40034/how-to-delete-a-column-in-a-content-type](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/40034/how-to-delete-a-column-in-a-content-type)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the poowershell script to delete the Column from Content Type.

```
#Attach to the web and content type
$web = Get-SPWeb http://portal
$ct = $web.ContentTypes["Sales Document"]

#Get link to the columnn from the web
$spFieldLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink ($web.Fields["Aliases"])

#Remove the column from the content type and update
$ct.FieldLinks.Delete($spFieldLink.Id)
$ct.Update()

#Dispose of the web object
$web.Dispose()
```

http://get-spscripts.com/2010/10/cant-remove-site-column-from-content.html

Note. Always Test it in Dev Farm or site 1st.

Comment: Here is what I typed into PowerShell and it didn't have any effect.
`code`
$web = Get-SPWeb http://rex
$ct = $web.ContentTypes["Item"]
$spFieldLink = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldLink ($web.Fields["Name"])
$ct.FieldLinks.Delete($spFieldLink.Id)
$ct.Update()
$web.Dispose()
`code`

Comment: column is still exist, after this? may be refresh the page, close the browser or reopen it

Comment: Closed and reopened browser (IE 9.0) and it's still there.